# How does Killmonger so easily defeat T'Challa in ritual combat?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

In Black Panther, Killmonger is shown to defeat T'Challa in ritual combat without much effort.

However, before the fight, T'Challa drinks a potion which gives him the powers of the Black Panther.

How can a regular human soldier (regardless of how many regular people he has killed) so easily overpower a hero with superhuman strength, agility and resilience?

Comment: He drinks that to *strip* his Black Panther power so it's a fair fight.

Comment: @Plexus Oh! Now I see that was the cause of confusion, that clears things up!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've misunderstood what's happening.  The potion T'Challa drinks strips him of the Black Panther powers and reverts him to normal human levels.  This is to allow the combat to be fair.

If T'Challa had the Black Panther powers odds are good that he'd have won the fight.

As it was, Killmonger won due to what appeared to be purely superior skill and strength.